# the convex and concave lines on the PDF

Tags: modeling, export

I am trying to make a paper template to make a 3D paper model. when I export the model with the paper model add-on it only shows solid black lines, I can't tell which needs to be folded in or out. even when I specify to have anything but solid lines, like a dotted or dashed line, the PDF still only has solid black lines. if anyone knows how to specify on which way to fold the crease and to have it shown on the PDF it would be much appreciated.